# Access local storage within WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview, local-storage

First off I have seen there are other potentially related issues on here however the solutions offered have not solved my problem.

To try and help explain the problem I will cover what I am trying to achieve; an email is sent from our website inviting a user to sign up with our client app. The link in the email hits our website, stores an activation code and then redirects to the Google Play Store page. Once the user downloads the app and then works their way through the introduction screens it attempts to find the activation code by loading up a WebView. This is where things go wrong, currently it cannot find/access the local storage to get the activation code.

Here is what I currently have in place:

**App store redirection (the first link from the email)**

```
    <html><head></head><body>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            // The activation code goes in this url
            localStorage.setItem('url', '" + constructedUrl + "');
            setTimeout(function() { 
                window.location.href='BACK TO OUR SITE' }, 30000);
            setTimeout(function() { 
                window.location.href='GOOGLE PLAY STORE PAGE' }, 500);
        </script>
    </body></html>
```

**Permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Attempting to access activation code**

```
cookieWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
cookieWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
cookieWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
cookieWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
cookieWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());
// Call the AppActivate.html file.
cookieWebView.loadUrl(ServerCommunications.getRedirectUrl());

cookieWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
        Log.d("MyApplication", consoleMessage.message() + " -- From line "
                + consoleMessage.lineNumber() + " of "
                + consoleMessage.sourceId());
         return false;
    }
});
```

**App activation (loaded from the above WebView)**

```
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var appUrl = localStorage.getItem('url');

        console.log("URL is ");
        console.log(appUrl);

        if (appUrl) {
            localStorage.removeItem('url');
            location.href = appUrl;
        } else {
            location.href = "OUR SCHEME://?token=0";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I see when the app tries to activate is the following 2 lines logged:

```
09-18 09:06:30.151 4948-4948/our.namespace D/MyApplication: URL is  -- From line 10 of https://OURWEBSITE/AppActivate.html
09-18 09:06:30.152 4948-4948/our.namespace D/MyApplication: null -- From line 11 of https://OURWEBSITE/AppActivate.html
```

Which shows that either the value wasn't set in to Local Storage or it can't be accessed. I know that it has been stored because if I navigate to the above url from the standard browser on my Android device it gives me the value that I am expecting.

I can't work out if I am missing any hidden setting or if it is just not possible. I believe I have turned on anything related to permissions or settings for the WebView as suggested in other answers to possibly related questions. If it helps I am testing on a BlackView Android 6.0 phone.

Is there anything obvious that I am missing?

Comment: Any values set in the default Android web browser in local storage/cookies won't be visible in the WebView within your app. It's completely different instance of the browser.

Comment: We were able to achieve this on iOS through the use of the SafariViewController I guess I was expecting that Android would be less restrictive. Do you believe it would be possible to achieve something similar through the use of cookies and be able to access them from within our app?

Comment: According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html `For obvious security reasons, your application has its own cache, cookie store etc.—it does not share the Browser application's data. Cookies are managed on a separate thread, so operations like index building don't block the UI thread. Follow the instructions in CookieSyncManager if you want to use cookies in your application.`

Comment: What I would suggest perhaps is to use deep linking? So the flow would be like: 1. save the activation code as before in the local storage 2. when user downloads your app and goes thru the onboarding process include some button (or do it automatically) that opens up a web page in the system's browser. 3. Now you have access to the local storage where you saved your activation code. 4. On the website provide a deep linked button that has activation code in the url 5. User clicks it and goes back to your app where you can grab activation code from the Intent. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that does make sense thanks. I really didn't want to have to leave the app to get this information but it may be the only way. This process was implemented in the original app (iOS) to make it simpler for a user to sign up, jumping between the app and browser just makes it feel poor. Perhaps we will have to find another possible approach. Thanks though

Comment: You can also fiddle with referral links (search for: Google Play Campaign Measurement). You can access referral number within your app upon app downloading from Google Play Store. In that case you can omit accessing any local storage values and leaving your app.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns

Comment: I shall definitely look in to that thank you! If that solves it I'll let you know so you can claim the answer

Comment: @lukaleli that approach certainly does prove to be the one to use! I am having some issues with it working in a release build but that is most likely an issue with my implementation. Happy to approve an answer based on it.

Comment: Great! will add answer then to you to approve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html):

> For obvious security reasons, your application has its own cache,
>   cookie store etc.—it does not share the Browser application's data.
>   Cookies are managed on a separate thread, so operations like index
>   building don't block the UI thread. Follow the instructions in
>   CookieSyncManager if you want to use cookies in your application.

What I would suggest perhaps is to use deep linking. The flow would be something like:

1. Save the activation code as before in the local storage
2. When user downloads your app and goes thru the onboarding process
   include some button (or do it automatically) that opens up a web
   page in the system's browser.
3. Now you have access to the local storage where you saved your
   activation code.
4. On the website provide a deep linked button that has activation code
   in the url
5. User clicks it and goes back to your app where you can grab
   activation code from the Intent

If you don't want to break UX by leaving the app perhaps you should take a look at referral links (search for: `Google Play Campaign Measurement`). You can access referral number within your app upon app downloading from Google Play Store. In that case you can omit accessing any local storage values and leaving your app.

Comment: I went ahead and used the campaign measurement suggestion. I passed across the relevant information when redirecting to the Play Store and then consumed that information once the app runs.